# What is wrong with my 12 bit ADC SPI code?

Tags: c, stm32, spi, adc

So I am trying to read data from a strain load cell, which has a 2mV/V output, using the INA128P amplifier and LTC1296CCN ADC. The ADC datasheet states it works in half duplex operation and suggests a 3 wire bidirectional connection. To configure the ADC, after setting the CS low I should send an 8 bit word to the ADC's Din and then from the Dout a null bit, the 12 bit data and then zeros are transmitted until the CS goes high again. I have tried full duplex and half duplex but i keep receiving zeros from my code. Below is my code and the circuit (the parts are on a breadboard)

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c  
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

 /**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    char uart_buf[100];
    char boofer[100];
    uint8_t ADC_buf[2];
    uint8_t input_word[2];
    int uart_buf_len;
    int length;
    uint16_t testdata[100];
    uint8_t i = 0;
    uint16_t sample;
   /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  // CS pin should default high
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    uart_buf_len = sprintf(uart_buf, "SPI test\r\n");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)uart_buf, uart_buf_len, 100);
    //input word is 10100110
    input_word[0] = 167;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        //HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, input_word, 1, 100);
        //HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, ADC_buf, 2, 100);
        HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, input_word, ADC_buf, 2, 100);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        sample = (((uint16_t) ADC_buf[0] << 9)|(((uint16_t)ADC_buf[1] << 1))) >> 4;
        testdata[i] = sample;
        //uart_buf_len = sprintf(uart_buf, testdata[i]);
        //HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint16_t *)uart_buf, 2);
        length =sprintf(boofer,"%d\n",testdata[i])  + 1;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, boofer, length, 100);
        i++;
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
   }
   /* USER CODE END 3 */


}
```

[Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI1p4.png)

Comment: Please include an oscilloscope waveform or logic analyzer trace if possible.

Comment: Please read page 15 of [LTC1296 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/129346fs.pdf) to understand what you need to send and how many bytes you need to send in order to get the data.